# Change Ion-Title text programatically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've recently picked up Ionic Framework to do an app. All is going well but I'm having issues with a rather small part but annoying.

I've implemented swiperJS which works ok, I'm now wanting to show the current index of which slide you are on in the ion-title object. I have got the index spitting out to the console fine and putting it into a variable but what I thought would have worked didn't. It just doesn't update the title, it only accepts the initial number I gave it.

register.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

  private slides: any;
  slideIndex: number;

  swiperConfig: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    navigation: false
  };

  constructor() {
    this.slideIndex = 1;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  setSwiperInstance(swiper: any) {
    this.slides = swiper;
  }

  onSlideChange(){
    
    this.slideIndex = this.slides.activeIndex + 1;
    console.log(this.slideIndex);
  }
}
```

register.page.html

```
<ion-header color="primary">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title class="ion-text-center">Step {{slideIndex}}</ion-title>
    <div class="wizardProgress ion-text-center"></div>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <swiper color="primary" (swiper)="setSwiperInstance($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()" [config]="swiperConfig">
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 4</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 5</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 6</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 7</ng-template>
  </swiper>
</ion-content>
```

I've tried replacing the whole title as per another question posted, I've tried setting it all as a string too. As I mentioned, it should alter the title to say 'Step 1', 'Step 2' etc but it just stays at 'Step 1' even though the slide changes and the variable (slideIndex) changes too which I can see from the console output.

Any ideas why it won't change? I can see the variable in the background change but it just won't render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `activeIndexChange` event and recovery the `activeIndex` with the swiper object.

Your HTML:

```
 <swiper color="primary" (activeIndexChange)="activeIndexChange($event)" (swiper)="setSwiperInstance($event)" [config]="swiperConfig">
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
    ...
  </swiper>
```

Your .ts:

```
 activeIndexChange(swiper) {
     this.slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex
 }
```

If still don't updating, try using change detector:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor (private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and after the `this.slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex` you call:

```
activeIndexChange(swiper) {
     this.slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
     this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
 }
```

Comment: hey, thank you for that. It does make it a little more streamlined but the title still doesn't update.

Comment: I just update my answer with `ChangeDetectorRef`. Check that

Comment: Perfect!!!! Working now, thank you!